# What is causing this exception? Is the constructor for loop unnecessary?

Tags: java

```
     import java.util.*;
        public class UserInput {
            public static void main(String[]args){
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("How many students are in your class?");
                Student.n= input.nextInt();
                ArrayList<Student> manyStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
                for(int i=0; i<Student.n; i++){
                    manyStudents.add(new Student(null, null, null, null, 0));
                }

            }
        }
```

This main method calls upon the public class Student to create a number of object instances that include the Student's first name last name HKID SID and exam grade and stores each object instance in another array deemed manyStudents. The question regards the compilation error received during run time shown in the latter part of the explanation.

```
        import java.util.*;
        public class Student {
            public static String []  first;
            public static String [] last;
            public static String [] HKID;
            public static String[] SID;
            public static int []Exam;
            public static int n;


            public Student (String f, String l, String h, String s, int e){
                Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                    System.out.println("First name:");
                    first[i]=f= kb.next();
                    System.out.println("Last name:");
                    last[i]=l=kb.next();
                    System.out.println("HKID:");
                    HKID[i]=h=kb.next();
                    System.out.println("SID:");
                    SID[i]=s=kb.next();
                    System.out.println("Final exam score:");
                    Exam[i]=e=kb.nextInt();
                }
            }

            public String[] getFirst(){return first;}
            public String [] getLast(){return last;}
            public String [] getHKID(){return HKID;}
            public String [] getSID(){return SID;}
            public int [] getExam(){return Exam;}
            public void setFirst(String [] f){f=first;}
            public void setLast(String [] l){l=last;}
            public void setHKID(String [] h){h=HKID;}
            public void setSID(String [] s){s= SID;}
            public void setExam(int [] e){e=Exam;}
        }
```

In run time I am receiving an error after it asks for the first name. The error reads:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Student.<init>(Student.java:15)
        at UserInput.main(UserInput.java:9)
```

Is the "i" in the student constructor interfering with the allocation of the variables to each object instance. The code seems to make logical sense to me, so I am not sure the reason for error during run time.  Perhaps the for loop in the constructor is unnecessary...I am not confident in any reason. Can someone please explain????

Comment: That's not a compilation error. That's a runtime exception.

Comment: Interesting! Did you know that your loop wouldn't work if the condition was not evaluated just once (at the beginning)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your arrays, for example:

```
first = new String[n];
```

before you can use `first[i]`. Same for `last` & co.

Also you seem to expect that `f = kb.next()` is doing something but it's not doing anything in your current code.